# TCP client reconnect to server if the server is down (using Asyncio)

Tags: python, tcp, python-asyncio

I am writing a program using asyncio in python where a Client connects to a server, they exchange some messages and the Server closes the connection.
What I also need to implement is a retry mechanism, where in case the server is down the client will keep trying to reconnect every 5 seconds.

Being new in python and with the asyncio concept in general, I need help to understand how to implement that.
Below is a snippet of my code where I start the connection with the server and where I handle it in case of socket closure on server side.

```
async def main():
    # Get a reference to the event loop as we plan to use
    # low-level APIs.
    format = "%(asctime)s: %(message)s"
    logging.basicConfig(format=format, level=logging.INFO,
                        datefmt="%H:%M:%S")

    executor1 = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2)
    future1 = executor1.submit(init_thread)

    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    on_con_lost = loop.create_future()

    message = future1.result()
    message = struct.pack(">I", len(message)) + bytes(message, "utf-8")

    transport, protocol = await loop.create_connection(
        lambda: EchoClientProtocol(message, on_con_lost),
        '127.0.0.1', 9000)

    # Wait until the protocol signals that the connection
    # is lost and close the transport.
    try:
        await on_con_lost
    finally:
        transport.close()

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: What are `init_thread` and `EchoClientProtocol`? Why are you using low-level transport/protocol layer instead of the recommended [streams layer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html)?

Comment: I use init_thread to create an identification message that is to be sent to the Server at first connection, while EchoClientProtocol is a class that implements all the methods for the connection such as: data_received(), send(), connection_made(), connection_lost(). To be honest I took that code example in the beginnings when I first found out about asyncio and built my code upon it. Do you suggest I should change my approach to the one you've suggested? Appreciate your response!

Comment: It's hard to help you when without a minimal example showing the code. In either case, you should use the streams API which is both recommended and easier to use, especially when implementing control flow needed for reconnection.

Comment: Also, your code would leave a better impression if you at least took care to rename the "echo client" example class to something that doesn't have "echo client" in its name. :)

Comment: Thanks for the answers, really appreciate your feedback. In that case I will try to rewrite the code using the streams API and will come back in case I need any further help. Cheers!

Comment: The advantage of streams is that they expose a coroutine interface to the underlying sockets and are not based on callbacks, while remaining fully async. That way you can write a simple `while` loop and do reconnects in the obvious way, by handling socket exceptions just like you'd do with blocking code.